# How can i manipulate the Font Properties in c# on a run time

Tags: c#, .net, windows, winforms, charts

I really am new on this trying to manipulate the font property of a text or chart title in c# windows form

so far i tried this ones:

```
Font font = new System.Drawing.Font(FontStyle.Bold) <-- it wouldn't do debugging

Chart1.Title[0].Font = new Font(Chart1.Title[0].Font, 
Chart1.Title[0].Font.Style | FontStyle.Bold); <-- this got pass to debugging by no effect

Chart1.Title[0].Font(FontStyle.Bold); <-- so is this one pass debugging but no effect.
```

i got Hands up on trying to set it's text to bold in windows form i've done it but only at a web apps which pretty much simplier **Title / Or some Text**

how do i set it's propert title font to change the text to bold instead of normal fontstyle?

Comment: What do you mean by "it wouldn't do debugging"? What do you mean by "I got Hands up"? Your question is very unclear.

Comment: On top of what Jon said, try to make sure the code you put up is as free from syntax errors as you can get it. By that I mean the 2nd and 3rd lines of your code shouldn't compile as they currently are.

Comment: @Jon Skeet sorry sir what i mean is "it wouldn't do debugging" i tried it running visual studion it has already errors so it won't pass when i try to run it. if "it got pass to debugging" meaning the codes run no error but it has no effect on what i'm trying to display..

Comment: @Jon Skeet and also "I got hands up" it means i surrender already researching and do stuff just to get the right of it. so i ask question then.

Comment: If you're getting errors, please say what those errors are, *always*. If you get an exception, tell us that as well.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
   Title title = Chart1.Titles.Add("Test");
   title.Font = new System.Drawing.Font("Arial", 16, FontStyle.Bold);
   title.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.FromArgb(0, 0, 205);
```